# Avoid user to open original .php with .htaccess

Tags: .htaccess, mod-rewrite

I've mapped my website like this on the .htaccess file:

```
RewriteRule ^about/?$ /about.php [QSA,L]
```

That's fine, they will open **example.com/about** but I do not want them to be able to open **example.com/about.php**

Any way I can avoid that in my .htaccess file?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can try this:

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteRule ^about\.php?$ /about/ [R]
RewriteRule ^about/?$ /about.php [QSA,L]
```